# combine the two JSON Objects depending on the ids

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to combine two JSON objects using angular and create a single object. somehow i am able to do it but a small glitch not able to find what can be done for that .. below are the two JSON objects:

```
    var array1 = [
            {
        "personId" : 7,
        "batchNumber": 213,
        "name": "Mike",
        "company":"abc"
    }];

        var array2 = [
            {
        "batchNumber": 213,
        "role": "engineer"

    },
    {
        "batchNumber": 213,
        "role": "architect"
    }];
```

i want the resultant json to be

```
var result = [
{
        "personId" : 7,
        "batchNumber": 213,
        "name": "Mike",
        "company":"abc",
        "role": "engineer"
    }
    {
        "personId" : 7,
        "batchNumber": 213,
        "name": "Mike",
        "company":"abc",
        "role": "architect"
    }]
```

I am able to create only one json out of it and then the loop is terminated/ Any help would be grateful thanks in advance.

```js
var array1 = [{
  "personId" : 7,
  "batchNumber": 213,
  "name": "Mike",
  "company":"abc"
}, {
  "personId" : 8,
        "batchNumber": 218,
        "name": "julie",
        "company":"tyu"
}];

var array2 = [{
        "batchNumber": 213,
        "role": "engineer"

    },
    {
        "batchNumber": 213,
        "role": "architect"
    },{
        "batchNumber": 218,
        "role": "BSA"

    },
    {
        "batchNumber": 218,
        "role": "Manager"
    }];

var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  var obj = array1[i];
 if (array2[i] && obj.box == array2[i]._id) {
   for (key in array2[i]) {
      obj[key] = array2[i][key];
    }
    newArray.push(obj);
  }
};

console.log(newArray);
```

I'm attaching the JS fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/n9pv4pL3/

My Controller:

```
var array1 = [
        {
    "personId" : 7,
    "batchNumber": 213,
    "name": "Mike",
    "company":"abc"
}];

    var array2 = [
        {
    "batchNumber": 213,
    "role": "engineer"

},
{
    "batchNumber": 213,
    "role": "architect"
}];

    var newArray = [], i,key;
    for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        var obj = array2[i];
        if (array1[i] && obj. INPT_FILE_ID == array1[i].INPT_FILE_ID) {
            for (key in array1[i]) {
                obj[key] = array1[i][key];
            }
            newArray.push(obj);
        }
    };
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: fiddle link missing

Comment: Pravin Umamaheswaran i attached the fiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var array1 = [
                {
                    "personId": 7,
                    "batchNumber": 213,
                    "name": "Mike",
                    "company": "abc"
                }];

                var array2 = [
                {
                    "batchNumber": 213,
                    "role": "engineer"

                },
                  {
                      "batchNumber": 213,
                      "role": "architect"
                  }];

                var finalData = [];
                array1.forEach(data => {
                    //filter batchwise data
                    var dataFromArray2 = array2.filter(arry2 => {               
                   return arry2.batchNumber === data.batchNumber });
                    //pushing data in main array
                    dataFromArray2.forEach(batchData => {
                        finalData.push({
                            personId: data.personId,
                            batchNumber: batchData.batchNumber,
                            name: data.name,
                            company: data.company,
                            role: batchData.role
                        });
                    });
                });
                console.log(finalData)
```

here it's run fine,please check it once again,I have also added snippet for that
and about filter method
which is Returns the new filtered array. 
in our case it's return new array with all properties of array2
if you want to understand in deap then refer this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: thanks for your response kushal i tried the way you suggested, it is giving me the empty array .. and one more thing could you please explain is the job of filter in here thanks in advance

Comment: annie i have added snippet please check it and edit asnwer

Comment: thanks for your response kushal it worked for me with few more modifications

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want to aggregate all roles under one key you could do it with 2 reduce functions like this:

```
 let workingArray = array1.reduce((prevVal, currVal, index) => {
   let role = array2.reduce((rPrevVal, rCurrVal, idx) => {
     if (currVal.batchNumber === rCurrVal.batchNumber) {
       rPrevVal.push(rCurrVal.role);
     }
     return rPrevVal;
   }, []);
   prevVal.push({
     ...currVal,
     role
   });
   return prevVal;
 }, []);

 console.log(workingArray);
```

There's probably less complex solution, but what can I say I like reduce function:) Check fiddle here (in console) I added 2 different objects in first array and more objects in second:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/pegla/v4qqs3dk/2/